# How can I convert str list items into dict and while the list items have the same structure of dict

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a list into dict
the list have a dict structure which I need to get a specific object from the dict in the end, I can get a specific date from the following output and compare it with another

i have this code

```
    aapi_billing = execute_command(<some command returned dict structure >)
        for i in aapi_billing:
            print(i)
```

which returned

```
 {
  "tenantId": "endurance-aus-2-4188",
  "totalExecutions": 0
},
{
  "tenantId": "endurance-aus-2-4221",
  "totalExecutions": 0
},
{
  "tenantId": "endurance-aus-2-4324",
  "totalExecutions": 0
},
{
  "tenantId": "endurance-tlv-1-4188",
  "totalExecutions": 0
},
{
  "tenantId": "endurance-tlv-1-4221",
  "totalExecutions": 0
},
{
  "tenantId": "endurance-tlv-1-4324",
  "totalExecutions": 0
},
{
  "tenantId": "endurance-tlv-2-4188",
  "totalExecutions": 0
},
{
  "tenantId": "endurance-tlv-2-4221",
  "2020-10-27": {
    "jobExecutions": 3299
  },
  "2020-10-28": {
    "jobExecutions": 20129
  },
  "2020-10-29": {
    "jobExecutions": 20085
  },
  "2020-10-30": {
    "jobExecutions": 20149
  },
  "2020-10-31": {
    "jobExecutions": 20176
  },
  "2020-11-01": {
    "jobExecutions": 20145
  },
  "2020-11-02": {
    "jobExecutions": 26117
  },
  "2020-11-03": {
    "jobExecutions": 26123
  },
  "totalExecutions": 156223
},
{
  "tenantId": "endurance-tlv-2-4324",
  "totalExecutions": 0
},
{
  "tenantId": "endurance-tlv-3-4188",
  "totalExecutions": 0
},
{
  "tenantId": "endurance-tlv-3-4221",
  "totalExecutions": 0
},
{
  "tenantId": "endurance-tlv-3-4324",
  "totalExecutions": 0
}
```

in the end, I would like to get the dict object after "tenantId": "endurance-tlv-2-4221"

Comment: Is this a string?  What are the ** in the output?

Comment: yes its a list of string, the ** I tried to bold the part that I need to get